# Send List of object by ref in c++

Tags: list, visual-c++, pointers

I try in c++ to send a list by ref,
my code is:
I want to add to listOfLectures the object it but it does not work

```
    void Subject::getSubjectList(list<Subject>& listOfLectures)
    list<Subject*>::iterator it;
    for(it=nodeSons.begin(); it != nodeSons.end(); ++it) 
         listOfLectures.insert(it);
```

Comment: Does nodeSons hold a list of pointers to Subject? To be sure..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
list<Subject*>::iterator it; 
for(it=nodeSons.begin(); it != nodeSons.end(); ++it)
     listOfLectures.insert(**it);
```

I'm assuming nodeSons is a list of pointers to Subjects. Meaning you have to dereference the iterator twice.